# How to start a populated listview to start at top with flutter? Populated listview pushes up container when I don't want it to

Tags: flutter

When I make a listview that is populated and go to that view. It starts the view towards the bottom of the list with what was added most recently to that listview. I want to keep a box with relevant information at the top or within view initially. Then have the user scroll through the list. How can this be done? The listview is already populated.
[image]

The right is what happens, but I want the left. I currently have to scroll up to see what is at the top. It gets pushed off screen when the list gets large enough.

Comment: Wrap your `ListView` with a `Column` and wrap `ListView` with `Expanded` then as the first child of the `Column` add any widget that you want.

Comment: Currently I have it within a Listview and it cannot readily be changed without major changes. Is it possible to have it start off scrolling at the top of the listview instead of the bottom?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Does the `reverse: true` field fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After some rewriting of my code to take advantage of [showSearch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showSearch.html) and [SearchDelegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html). (You can find a good example of how to use those by watching [this episode](https://youtu.be/Wm3OiFBZ2xI) of the boring show.)

I solved my question by doing the following based on what [balsanka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3675035/blasanka) suggested. Here is some pseudo code of what I did to fix. This future builder is within my Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) inside my SearchDelegate class.

```html
FutureBuilder (
...
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<> snapshot) {
  ...
    ListView retList = ListView(
      ...
    )
    ...
    Column ret = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Text('AYYYYY it worked'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: retList,
        )
      ],
    );
    return ret;
  }
)
```

Thanks for all the help guys!